# iOS SDK | NMAMapOverlay didn't displayed at right place

Tags: ios, react-native, here-api

#### Requirements :

I am try to show a overlay as info bubble when I am select a marker.

#### What did I do:

Created coords by `NMAGeoCoordinates *coords = [[NMAGeoCoordinates alloc] initWithLatitude:_coordinate.latitude                                                   longitude:_coordinate.longitude];`

create a marker by `[[NMAMapMarker alloc] initWithGeoCoordinates:coords icon:markerImage];`

added it to map `[mapView addMapObject:marker.marker];`

created mapOverlay `self.overlayView = [[NMAMapOverlay alloc] initWithSubview:label geoCoordinates: coords];`

added it to map  `[mapView addMapOverlay:self.overlayView];`

coords are same and didn't changed all time.

#### Expected result

MapOverlay should displayed at same place as MapMarker.

#### Actually result

MapOverlay displayed at few streets away

[image]

## Environment

iOS simulator with iOS 12.1

here map iOS SDK v3.10.1_96

React-native 0.55.0

Comment: `marker.marker = [[NMAMapMarker alloc] initWithGeoCoordinates:coords icon:markerImage];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue. It looks like there is something else failing. We will analyze this and come back to you.

Comment: Update: You will find a workaround provided on github https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/issues/92#issuecomment-468362847

The fix will be delivered in 3.11